# React setState won't update, if I add an if statement

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying to create a simple tic tac toe game, nothing special.
There's the part of the code I'm having trouble with:

```
   const [player,setPlayer]=useState("O")
const [board, setBoard]=useState([null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null])    //9 db

const renderCell=(i)=>{
    return <Cell handleClick={handleClick} id={i} value={board[i]}/>
}
const handleClick=(e)=>{
    let id=parseInt(e.target.id)
    setBoard((prev)=>{
        let newBoard=prev
        console.log(newBoard[id])
        if(newBoard[id]===null){

            newBoard[id]=player
            console.log(board)
            updatePlayer()
        }
        return newBoard
    })
}

const updatePlayer=()=>{
    setPlayer(current=>{
        return current==="X"?"O":"X"
    })
}
```

the problem is, the update player only updates once, from 'O' to 'X' then it stays X.
However, if I remove the ' if(newBoard[id]===null)' statement, it works like charm, but of course this way the player could alter the previous 'O' or 'X' signs.
This code is working, and the only difference is the missing if statement:

```
const [player,setPlayer]=useState("O")
const [board, setBoard]=useState([null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null])    //9 db

const renderCell=(i)=>{
    return <Cell handleClick={handleClick} id={i} value={board[i]}/>
}
const handleClick=(e)=>{
    let id=parseInt(e.target.id)
    setBoard((prev)=>{
        let newBoard=prev
        console.log(newBoard[id])
            newBoard[id]=player
            console.log(board)
            updatePlayer()
        return newBoard
    })
}

const updatePlayer=()=>{
    setPlayer(current=>{
        return current==="X"?"O":"X"
    })
}
```

Comment: I figured this is because of asynchronisity, so return newBoard runs before updatePlayer does but then why the first change?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but since you shouldn't mutate the existing state, you shouldn't do `let newBoard=prev` but `const newBoard = [...prev]`

Comment: you said not an answer, but it actually solved the problem :O
But why tho? I don't understand why did it solved this

Comment: I had a feeling it might.

Comment: I'm writing up an explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite the `handleClick` function like this

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
    let id = parseInt(e.target.id)
    if (board[id] != null) {
      return
    }

    setBoard(board.map((el, i) => i === id ? player : el))
    setPlayer(player === "X" ? "O" : "X")
};
```

Comment: It depends on what you want from your component, but your method makes `handleClick` not memoizable, adds a loop with logic (`.map`) over the entire `board`, and switches player even if "x" clicked on "x" or "o" clicked on "o".

Comment: You missed the statement `if (board[id] != null) { return; }`, so it will not switch player if "x" clicks on "x" or "o". Please look at the answer carefully before adding negative points

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, react performs some optimizations because each render might be costly. For example, this won't trigger a re-render:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(0)
useEffect(() => {
  setState(0)
})
```

because even though `setState` is called, the identity of the component's state (and props) hasn't changed: `0 === 0`.

In your case, the state is an object (technically an array, but in JS it's all the same). So you can "change" it without losing the identity. For example, this won't trigger a re-render:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(['a'])
useEffect(() => {
  setState(prev => {
    prev[0] = 'b'
    return prev
  })
})
```

What you are trying to do is very similar to this last example:

```js
const a = ['O']
const b = a
b[0] = 'X'
console.log(a === b) // true
```

In order to lose identity (so that the component re-renders), you should "clone" the array. An easy way to do that is with destructuring:

```js
const newBoard = [...prev]
// ...
return newBoard
```

So the full answer with your example would be:

```
const handleClick=(e)=>{
    let id=parseInt(e.target.id)
    setBoard((prev)=>{
        let newBoard=[...prev]
        if(newBoard[id]===null){
            newBoard[id]=player
            updatePlayer()
        }
        return newBoard
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So after Sheraff's answer: I shouldn't do `let newBoard=prev` but const newBoard = [...prev]

```
const handleClick=(e)=>{
    let id=parseInt(e.target.id)
    setBoard((prev)=>{
        const newBoard=[...prev]
        if(newBoard[id]===null){
            newBoard[id]=player
            updatePlayer()
        }
        return newBoard
    })
}
```